# Fourier series of a weird piecewise function

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

consider the function $f(x)$, which is defined as 
\begin{cases}
1,& -1\le x<0, \\
1/2, &\quad x=0, \\
x,& \phantom{-}0<x\le 1.
\end{cases}

This seemed a bit weird to me because of the value it takes at $x=0$, as it is not possible to find the Fourier coefficients for a single point, unless I am much mistaken. Do the sines and cosines just not contribute to the series for $x=0$ as they do with constant functions or is it just not possible to find the Fourier series for the function?

Comment: You find the Fourier series for the whole function, which I assume extends periodically with period 2. The coefficients are integrals over this period and are not found at a point. What happens at one point does not matter and can be ignored.

Comment: I haven’t done Fourier series in a long time, but I would have thought that you can kind of ignore that point at x=0 whilst figuring out the Fourier series for the rest of the function. Once you’ve figured out the Fourier series for the rest of the function, only then you can confirm that f(0) = 1/2 in your Fourier series function. $f_n(0)$ point-wise converges to 1/2.